# Angular parent component doesn't destroy child if child is saved in a @ViewChild variable

Tags: angular

I ran into a very weird bug yesterday, where i couldn't destroy the component I was at because it was saved in a variable in its parent. I know there are probably better ways to do it, but anyone knows why that could happen?

I was using ngbootstrap and the problem happened when I was trying to jump from one ngtabset tab into another programmatically using its select method. It also shows no error, it just doesn't go to the next tab. Here is ngtabset's code:
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabset/tabset.ts

This snippet should be also similar. When the child gets successfully destroyed, after we solved the first problem, the method in the parent component (setValue...()), that uses the child, also starts throwing an error.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
  <ngb-tabset (tabChange)="goToNextTab($event)">
    <ngb-tab id="childTab">
     <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Child</ng-template>
     <ng-template ngbTabContent>
       <child></child>
     </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab id="anotherTab">
     <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Title</ng-template>
     <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        Another Tab Content
     </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
   </ngb-tabset>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {
   @ViewChild(NgbTabset) tabset: NgbTabset;
   @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;
   childVar: boolean;

   goToNextTab(e){
     if(e.activeId === 'childTab') {
       e.preventDefault();
       this.setValueFromChildComponentHere();
       if(this.childVar) {
         this.tabset.select(e.nextId);

         // had to add this instead to make the select method function
         // this.childComponent = null;
         // this.tabset.select(e.nextId);
       }
     }

   }

   setValueFromChildComponentHere() {
     this.childVar = this.childComponent.var;

     // we had to do this to solve the second problem
     // if(this.childComponent !== null) {
     //  this.childVar = this.childComponent.var;
     // } else { 
     //  // value here doesn't matter
     //  this.childVar = false; 
     // }
   }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <button (click)="var = !var"></button>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  var: boolean;
}
```

Anyone knows why that happened?

Comment: Your description talks about ng-bootstrap and tabs. Your code doesn't have any of that. So what exactly is the actual problem, and where is the code allowing us to reproduce that problem? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Ok I tried to make the snippet as close as possible, and as simple as possible. The solution we had to do is commented beneath each problem.

Comment: Also seeing some typo error instead of 'if(childVar) {' it should be if(this.childVar) { .    right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I found a couple more typos and fixed them. Generally this snippet was written now, to make the code simple, and is not the actual code, so any typos don't relate to the problem. But the structure looks exactly the same.

Comment: It doesn't change to the next tab because you're calling preventDefault(). If the child variable is set, then you programmatically try to change tab, which calls the method again, which prevents the change to happen again, then change programmatically, and you end up with a stack overflow. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/api#NgbTabChangeEvent. Here's a stackblitz that actually compiles and reproduces the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hv83ve?file=app/parent.component.ts